Polymorphic Lazy loaded Type-Safe Vue Components
How can I switch between different Vue.js components representing the same view, while ensuring type safety and lazy loading on demand?
Example scenario: you need to dynamically load several filter  components with the same parameters on demand depending on type of filter needed. What is the best way to achieve this with proper typing and best TS and vue.js practices applied.

Self-answers are welcome on SO but the question still needs to conform the rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and not be just a prompt for a post. In case someone wants to suggest a different approach, t's unclear what you meant without looking into your own answer

@EstusFlask updated the question. hope followup clarification will make it clearer

Here is a detailed example of dynamic type-safe component loading.
You can use generic Component<PropType> type to define components with similar parameters.
So for instance, to dynamically load all components of certain type you can use this loader function.
type FilterCompName = "EasyFilter"  | "NameFilter"
type Proptype = { filter: string }
type FilteredComponent = Component<Proptype>

function loader<FilteredComponent>(comp: FilterCompName ): FilteredComponent  {
  return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./comps/${comp}.vue`))
}

Then you will have mapping array
type FilterNames= "easyFilter"  | "nameFilter"
const comps: { [id in FilterNames]: FilteredComponent} = {
  "easyFilter": loader("EasyFilter"),
  "nameFilter": loader("NameFilter")
} as const

Then just define ref for name and computed for the dynamically loaded async component
const filterString= ref<string>("test")
const name = ref<FilterNames>("easyFilter")
const ViewComp: ComputedRef<FilteredComponent> = computed(() => comps[name .value])

Then in template section you get dynamic component with correctly typed propertis
<template>
   <component  :is="ViewComp" :filter="filterString" />
</template>

Here is a working example

question asked at 14:46:18.  self-answered at 14:46:18.   ????

@yoduh this is a self-answered question

all answers are welcome. This is something I thought will be useful to many others and haven’t seen covered anywhere else
